# Add same machine to differnet juju model

Tags: juju, maas

Ubuntu : 18.04
MAAS: 2.4.2
juju : 2.5.4

How may I add same machine to different model at same time? Is it possible?

`juju models` output:

```
Model    Cloud/Region  Type  Status     Machines  Cores  Access  Last 
model1   maas-iaas     maas  available  3         19     admin   just now
model2   maas-iaas     maas  available  0         -      admin   41 second
```

So I have 3 physical machine assigned to model 1, how can I share same machine with model 2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. From within your controller, you can simply create another model on the same "cloud".

I assume that you've bootstrapped using something like this:

```
$ juju bootstrap mymaas c-1 # mymaas is the name of the MAAS cloud, 
                            # c-1 is the name of the controller
```

You now have two models established.

```
$ juju models
Controller: c-1

Model        Cloud/Region   # ...
controller   mymaas         # ...
default      mymaas         # ...
```

You should be able to add a model to that cloud right away:

```
$ juju add-model model2
```

`model2` should co-exist on the same hardware.

```
$ juju models
Controller: c-1

Model        Cloud/Region   # ...
controller   mymaas         # ...
default      mymaas         # ...
model2       mymaas         # ...
```

Comment: I updated the question, please see the clarification!